# SQL Insert to make all users friends with all

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables

```
1) USERS - List of all users
2) FRIENDS - List of users who are friends with each other
```

I want to make all users friends with all other users. So basically I need to insert all users info in the friends table.

**USERS Table Column**

```
1) id - user id of the user
2) name - user name
```

**Friends Table Column**

```
1) user_id
2) friend_id
```

**Question:**

I want to take an user from USERS table one by one and do a bulk insert in to FRIENDS table for the users who are not already friends.

I know I can check one by one with a JOIN and do something. But I don't think that's the easy and correct way of doing. Need some views from expert on this.

**Note:** Values in user_id and friend_id can be interchanged and it still means they are friends. There should not be a combination like (1,2) and (2,1).

**SQL Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/07b2d9/1

For the provided fiddle, all users must be made as friends for other user ignoring who are already friends.

Comment: Why would you want a complete friends graph? Is there any reason why you do not want to drop the friends table first and just add all combinations?

Comment: Nice idea. +1 for that. But even in that case, wouldn't we require a SQL to perform that. Also whenever a new user joins, it will force to drop the entire table again and again.

Comment: If you omit the where clause from cdhowie's answer, you get exactly that SQL. My first question was why you need a table containing all connections in the first place as it does not contain any useful information.

Comment: It was a requirement to that kind of data schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
insert into friends (user_id, friend_id)

select a.id as user_id,
       b.id as friend_id

-- Join users to itself.  The join constraint results in all of the combinations of
-- two friend IDs, rather than all of the permutations.
from users a
inner join users b on a.id < b.id

-- Remove rows from the results that have a matching row in the friends table.
where not exists (
  select f.user_id
  from friends f
  where ((f.user_id = a.id and f.friend_id = b.id) or
         (f.user_id = b.id and f.friend_id = a.id))
);
```

Comment: In this SQL, which is the best place to add a condition to insert the rows only for a particular user from USERS table? Say I want to insert friends for the user id 3.

Comment: @Purus `where (a.id = 3 or b.id = 3) and not exists ...`

Comment: So dear friends, what should I do now exactly considering comment of @spencer7593?

Comment: Oh. I see he removed the comment.. So I believe this is fine as it works for me.

Comment: @Purus: when i made my comment, the comment from cdhowie did not include `or b.id=3`. That's been added, so I removed my comment.

Answer (score 1):

To identify all combinations of users that are not a "friends" with other users, assuming that you only want one row (e.g. `(1,4)`) to represent the :friendship: and not both rows (e.g. `(1.4)`,`(4,1)`)

```
SELECT u.id  AS user_id
     , t.id  AS friend_id
  FROM users u
  JOIN users t
    ON t.id > u.id
  LEFT
  JOIN friends f
    ON f.user_id   = u.id
   AND f.friend_id = t.id 
  LEFT
  JOIN friends g
    ON g.user_id   = t.id
   AND g.friend_id = u.id
 WHERE f.user_id IS NULL
   AND g.user_id IS NULL
```

This query could be preceded by `INSERT INTO friends (user_id, friend_id)` to insert those rows into the friends table.

The join of the users table to itself gets all combinations, but we want to exclude rows where `user_id` and `friend_id` would have the same value; and we want only one side of the relationship, so we can exclude rows where user_id > friend_id.

To exclude rows that already exist in the friends table, we can use an anti-join pattern. Because we only want one of the two possible rows (1,4) or (4,1), and either of those could already exist, we perform the check both ways.

---

To do this for a single user, add:

```
    AND ( u.id = 4 OR t.id = 4 )
```

Comment: I believe the last 2 lines should be changed to reflect the correct column names. Does not execute due to this error.

Comment: @Purus: good catch. Answer update to reflect correct columns names.

Comment: @Purus: I seems to be MySQL so I'm not sure about that

Comment: It's possible that the two anti-joins (without any `OR` operators) may perform better than an `NOT EXISTS (correlated subquery)` and/or a single anti-join with an `OR` in the join predicate. (We'd expect MySQL would make use of a suitable index for any of those, and if the execution plans are different, determine which actually performs best. (In my experience, I've often gotten less optimal plans with `OR` conditions (in critical join/index predicates), and have gotten better performance with equivalent queries without an `OR`.

Comment: For improved performance, you'll want indexes `... ON friends (user_id,friend_id)` and `... ON friends (friend_id,user_id)`.